# SQL connection string and resolve domain name

Tags: database-connection, connection-string

We use this connection string today:

> Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=mydomain.com; Initial Catalog=myDB;User
>   Id=xxx; Password=xxx;

And I like to know who is save the mydomain.com in is cache, the browser of the user or the server that run the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is ASP.NET code, then the database connection happens on the server.  The user's browser has no knowledge of your database.

Comment: We are using Classic ASP. So the cache of the resolve domain will be in the server. does the server always go with the TTL of the domain or save different cache like most of the browser?

Comment: Unless it has been configured to do otherwise I would expect it to use the TTL specified by the domain.